# Rails asset pipeline: images not looking up resource with build id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a 404 on all of the images included with jquery-ui-rails on Rails 4.0.1 after going production. It works fine in development environment. The site is looking for `/assets/jquery-ui/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png`, but only `public/assets/jquery-ui/ui-icons_222222_256x240-890385424135de1513f00cbecfb7f990.png` exists in the filesystem. How come production build IDs are not being appended?

I've also had this problem with some fonts. For the time being I've worked around it by just manually copying and pasting to the sought path.

Comment: is this production on rails server or something like heroku?

Comment: No, it is running through Apache with Passenger.

Comment: you will need to paste some sample code of where you output the image tags

Comment: This is not affecting any image tags I've placed specifically. It's only affecting things like jquery-ui, where the DOM elements including image tags are created by JavaScript.

Comment: @cookiecaper - i mean is it failing on your local production server or only on an external/hosted server?  have you precompiled your assets?

Comment: It fails on the only production deployment I've done, which is a VPS from Linode. I've never not used "rails server" for my local, which works fine. And yes, I have cleaned and precompiled the assets with rake assets:clean and rake assets:precompile.

Comment: try `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`, does that change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to try is precompiling assets specifically for the production environment:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

If that doesn't do anything, set the following in `production.rb` and precompile again

```
config.assets.precompile += ['*.js', '*.css']
config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: Running precompile with the RAILS_ENV environment variable resolved the issue. Thanks!